# sum of random nunber of iid normal distributed random variables

Tags: probability-theory

Let $L$ be a random variable with $L(\omega) \in \{1,2,…\}$ for all $\omega \in \Omega$ and assume that $L$ has finite expectation $\mu_L$ and finite standard deviation $\sigma_L$.

Let $D_1,D_2,D_3\cdots$ be independently and identically distributed to the normal distribution $N(\mu_D,\sigma^2_D)$.

Suppose that $D_i$ and $L$ are independent.

Set $X=\Sigma_{i=1}^L D_i$.

I checked that

(1)$X$ is a random variable.

My question is that

is the distribution of $X$ a normal distribution?

I know that if $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are normally distributed, so is $Y_1+Y_2$.

Thank you!